# How to escape EL dollar signs?

Tags: jsp, escaping, el

I wish to write JSP which generates XML file, which has syntax, similiar to XML with EL expressions. In other words, I wish to let JSP to process only *my* expressions, but leave *foreign* expressions intact.

Is it possible to escape the EL like `${variable}` so that it get displayed as is?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can just put `\` in front to escape the EL expression:

```
\${variable}
```

Alternatively, you can XML-escape the `$`:

```html
&#36;{variable}
```