# JSP parses PrototypeJS template tags

Tags: jsp, prototypejs, jsp-tags

I'm using prototypejs templates on a JSP file.
But jsp file tries to parse #{} tags of prototypejs templates and hence it breaks.

How can I have jsp not parse them. I other words, how can I escape those tags?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `\#{}` as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8271033/how-to-escape-el-dollar-signs

Comment: I just did. Sorry but I didn't know about this feature.

Comment: Thats cool, you're not the only one to have missed that feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Escape it with `\`: `var template = new Template('<a href="\#{href}" title="\#{title}">\#{name}</a>');`
2. Encode it as entity: `var template = new Template('<a href="&#35;{href}" title="&#35;{title}">&#35;{name}</a>');`
3. Move it to JavaScript file.
4. Move it to Java code and write on JSP using EL `${}` or JSTL `<c:out />` or Stuts `<bean:write />`